# Updating the displayed URL in the browser using .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, controller

So, I have a certain webpage (view) that I have created. I have a requirement where I need to update the displayed URL in the browser's to show a different path to this page and update the querystring.

Update: I don't want to actually redirect the page, this is merely a cosmetic update. To make the URL appear differently that what it was. It's a requirement our customer support team wanted. :p

Ex.
https://www.myserver.com/error/

I need to update the path in the URL depending on the type of error, like so:
https://www.myserver.com/#/order-completed?var=someguid

My error page handles various situations you see.
I know this is easily done in JS, but I want to be able to do this from my error page Controller.

Could someone lend a hand? I'd super appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went the way of JS afterall. I call it from window.onload in the View.

```
var fromController = '@ViewData["NewURL"]';
histoy.pushState(null, '', fromController);
```

In the Controller, in the Index() action

```
ViewData["NewURL"] = @"/myURL/myview?user=2342434";
return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "update the path" means you simply have to redirect the browser to that url. If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can use the Redirect controller method like this:

```
return Redirect("https://www.myserver.com/#/order-completed?var=someguid");
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect the URL, it's only a cosmetic update to keep the customer support team happy.